# Which is best for Raspbian, 'udev' or 'mdev'?

Tags: raspbian, usb

I'm trying to detect when a mass storage USB device been inserted to my Pi. If it's a USB mass storage device(a pendrive), I want to transfer files from Pi to the pendrive and unmount automatically once the transfer is complete. (Right now I'm using my Pi for `TimeLapse` only)

When searching, some says `mdev` would serve for embedded purpose and is much more easier and also uses less memory than `udev`.

Which one would be the best? Has anyone have used `mdev` on your Pi so far?

I'm running Raspbian, and my hardware is B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When searching, some says mdev would serve for embedded purpose

A raspberry pi all by itself is not, in fact, a truly [embedded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) device, although it is akin to one and might be used to create or develop such things, which is why there is this association.  But it is really a general purpose computer like a PC.

Many embedded contexts involve systems which are much, much more limited than the pi; 512 MB of memory is easily several orders of magnitude greater than such systems.

Raspbian comes equiped with udev and that's what you should stick with.